# Change default lithium css

Tags: css, less, lithium

How can i setup lithium that it uses my own css file? And is it possible to use lesscss (http://lesscss.org/)?

Comment: You cannot! It's impossible! (dixit @gwoo)

Comment: not out of the box. but there is a solution for using using less which is based on php_less => not really nice but it is working. => http://mgcrea.github.com/li3_less/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about Lithium, the top-notch framework for bad-ass developers ?

If so, it's impossible !
Lithium styles are so sexy! Why the hell a developer would change those ?

More seriously, how can you ask this question ? :-)
Have at least read something about Lithium ?

PS: on your views/layout/default.html.php there is line where Stylessheets files are included.
Tweak it as you want, it's free !

PPS: and about less, sure you can ;-)